# Database initalizer and seeding data from an SQL script?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have a few tables that are created by entity framework that house my region and country data. I have a couple SQL scripts that I run after the model is updated, but it is becoming annoying to keep doing that. I would like to automate this a bit. Would I load my script into the Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() method of the context or is there a better way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No if you want automatic way there is no better approach then implementing derived initializer and use override `Seed` method which will load your scripts and execute them. That is why `Seed` method exists.